# Trying to replace a vanity light when the old one was mounted with a vertical brace behind the box

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, junction-box

[image]The electrical box behind the old vanity light was mounted with a junction box connected to a wall brace between studs.  Because of this, the holes on the junction box were at an angle, not horizontal. I need the holes to be horizontal in order to hang the new fixture.

What can I do so the junction box can connect to leave those wholes horizontally for the new fixture?

[image: box mounted in wall now, connected to metal brace]

Comment: Welcome. Can you add a picture?

Comment: this is how it was mounted, connected to a horizontal brace behind it.  There's no way to simply turn the blue box and still mount to the brace.  The new fixture needs to screw in with the holes horizontally.

Comment: Please also add a picture of the back of the new fixture. Often times, there is some flexibility in the mounting brackets that can accommodate the mounting holes not being horizontal

Answer (score 2):

Usually in cases like this you can use a rotational bracket, (shown below) which could be included with your fixture. If not, they are readily available at your home store. One bar gets screwed into the box and the other bar gets rotated to the position you need to align the fixture.

You might be able to just adjust the position of the lights by loosening the nut where the connections are made and then tightening it back up.

[image]

Comment: Because it's not suspended from the ceiling this will be prone to letting the light rotate on the wall if there are any forces on it.  I think the ring style one will help avoid this .... although it will require some effort.

Comment: @Judy if you'll take the [tour], you'll see that the appropriate way of saying "thanks" is to click the up arrow next to any an all answers that help you. In a day or so (others may have ideas, too), click the check mark next to the one you found _most_ helpful.

Comment: @jay613  You can tighten these up pretty good and the fixture will grab the wall.  I've never had any problems doing this. Plus, I've always put a small bead of caulk around the fixture after installing it due to it being in a bathroom.

Comment: Add that to the answer!   These are usually used on ceilings where they don't need to be tight.  Two good suggestions here -- tight to the wall and caulk.

Answer (score 2):

Use one of these

[image]

You'll have to replace the lamp's mounting screws and instead use nut, bolts, and lock washers.

Also, if you loosen this nut you might be able to turn the cover plate to match the wall box.
[image]

Comment: Went looking for this exact thing. Couldn't find the right search terms for it.

Comment: I have a pile of them in a box somewhere but I don't know what they're called.  "The thing that came with that light that I didn't use".  That's what they're called, right? :)

Comment: That is a beautifully lit product shot for having grabbed one out of the extra supplies box!

Comment: Rotating the cover plate is a good idea, but it would annoy the _heck_ out of me seeing the bolt heads not level every morning.

Comment: It is called a [universal crossbar](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=universal+crossbar)